# Copying and pasting from ubuntu thru putty to another computer

Tags: paste

I am trying to copy code from a forum then paste it thru putty to a nano editor file.
Can't seem to get it to paste into nano.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> ?

Alternatively, sometimes I paste via by right clicking and selecting from the context menu.

Comment: You might find you can paste with the middle mouse button as well.

Comment: Usually, I'm on a laptop-- I'm not sure which touchpad 'gesture' is middle-click. Right-click is tapping two fingertips with a multi-touch touchpad and the proper software...

Just the same, neat to know.